# Double file upload in session when using multiple file upload in jQuery ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I use this code for multiple upload with `jQuery` `ajax` in `ASP.NET` `MVC`:

```
public ActionResult GetFiles(HttpPostedFileBase NewsFilePath)
{
    if (NewsFilePath != null)
    {
        var files = Session["Files"] == null ?
            new List<HttpPostedFileBase>() :
            (List<HttpPostedFileBase>)Session["Files"];
        files.Add(NewsFilePath);
        Session["Files"] = files;
    }
    return Content("");
}
```

but I have problem with this code.

- when I upload one file, one file is stored into the session
- when I upload two files, 4 files is stored into the session
- when I upload three files, 6 files are stored into the session

What's the problem ?

Comment: You are attaching it one by one or selects all and call getfiles multiple times?

Comment: You seem to be always adding to the `"Files"` list which is stored in the session. So this list will keep getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: @Amit attach one by one

Comment: @DarinDimitrov how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: That would depend on what you are trying to achieve. You haven't provided any context about your application.

Comment: Try this `Session["Files"] = files.Distinct();`

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid where i use this ?

Comment: When assigning files to your Session.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid please write code .  please

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Distinct()` while assigning files to the `Session`

```
    public ActionResult GetFiles(HttpPostedFileBase NewsFilePath)
    {
        if (NewsFilePath != null)
        {
            var files = Session["Files"] == null ?
                new List<HttpPostedFileBase>() :
                (List<HttpPostedFileBase>)Session["Files"];
            files.Add(NewsFilePath);
            Session["Files"] = files.Distinct();
        }
        return Content("");
    }
```

Hopefully, it will solve your problem, if not, post a comment below.

Comment: Ok, let me change the logic, I'll update the answer after some time.